# Obtaining predicted values of the outcome variable using margins command

Tags: r, stata, nnet, marginal-effects

I have fit a multinomial logistic model as shown below. Using the margins command, I would like to obtain the predicted values for my outcome variable while setting the predictors to some specific values. In other words, I would like to replicate the Stata code below. Chatgpt gave me code that I pasted below as well but it returns an error of "Error in find_terms_in_model.default(model, variables = variables): Some values in 'variables' are not in the model terms."

**my multinomial logist code**

```
library(nnet)
model <- multinom(obesity_E ~ age_100 + I(age_100^2) + obesity + age_100:obesity +
                  covid:race + age_100:race + education + education:race +
                  rabplace_5, data = female_98_2020, maxit=1000)
```

**Code suggested by ChatGPT**

```
margins_model <- margins(model, variables = "obesity:race:rabplace_5",
                         at = list(age_100 = seq(0, 25, 1)), atMethod = "mean",
                         method = "probs", force = TRUE, noSe = TRUE,
                         save = "tran_point_F", replace = TRUE)
```

**My Stata code**

```
margins  , at (age_100=(0 (1) 25) obesity=(1 (1) 4) race=(0 (1) 3) rabplace_5=(1 (1) 5)) atmeans force nose saving(tran_point_F, replace )
```

Answer (score 2):

The `margins` package only computes slopes, not predictions. Also, that package is not being actively maintained and developed anymore (perhaps only critical bug fixes).

You can use [the `marginaleffects` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) instead, which is a newer package I developed as a more flexible successor to `margins` (note: conflict of interest).

See this vignette for a syntax comparison with Stata: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/alternative_software.html

The code you need will probably look similar to this:

```r
library(nnet)
library(marginaleffects)

m <- multinom(Species ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris, trace = FALSE)

avg_predictions(m, newdata = datagrid(Petal.Length = c(1, 4, 6)))
# 
#       Group Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)    S  2.5 % 97.5 % Petal.Width Petal.Length
#  setosa        0.333     0.0479 6.95  < 0.001 38.0 0.2389  0.427         1.2            1
#  versicolor    0.382     0.1195 3.20  0.00139  9.5 0.1477  0.616         1.2            4
#  virginica     0.285     0.1192 2.39  0.01672  5.9 0.0516  0.519         1.2            6
# 
# Columns: rowid, group, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, Species, Petal.Width, Petal.Length
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful clarification! In your suggested solution, we set the values for Petal.Length to be 1, 4, and 6. If this is correct, I wonder what values are set for Petal.Width? Also, I wonder how the below-suggested code is different than yours: Petal: predicted_probs <- predict(model, newdata = datagrid(Petal.Length = c(1, 4, 6)), type = "probs")

Comment: `datagrid` sets other variables to their means, but that can be customized. See the documentation. In this case, there should be no difference between the two, except that `predictions()` and `avg_predictions()` return uncertainy estimates. There are a ton of examples and detailed tutorials in the Predictions vignette here: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/predictions.html